# Does Random.nextInt(int) return negative values using java?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

```
public void click_random_retailer() 
{
    int randomNumber = new Random().nextInt(discoverPageObjects.merchantDivs.size() - 1) + 1;
    WebElement div = discoverPageObjects.merchantDivs.get(randomNumber);
    retailerName = div.findElement(By.cssSelector(discoverPageObjects.merchantNameLoc)).getText();
    System.out.println("Going to click Merchant ->  " + retailerName);
    WebElement merchantBtn = div.findElement(By.cssSelector(discoverPageObjects.merchantBtnLoc));
    merchantBtn.click();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No.  From the [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-):

> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from this random number generator's sequence.

As an aside, the [range of the parameterless version of nextInt is Integer.MIN_VALUE to Integer.MAX_VALUE, inclusive](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt--).

Proof that it can return negative numbers:

```
$ cat r.java
import java.util.Random;

public class r {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Random random = new Random();
        for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
            System.out.println(random.nextInt());
        }
    }
}
$ javac -d . r.java
$ java -cp . r | grep -- - | wc -l
49
```